# How to Refresh ListView on Tabbed Android Application?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabhost

I have an android tabbed application and inside one of my tabs is an activity that has a ListView of favorite items.
The user can add or remove items in an activity that is further down the flow.
 The problem is, I can't reload the list when user comes back.
onResume does not get called so I dont know when I should reload the list.


EDIT


This is how I'm starting the subsequent activities.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, CargasCadastro.class);
// Create the view using Group's LocalActivityManager
Window win = CargasGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("CargasCadastro",i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
View guialayout = win.getDecorView();
// Again, replace the view
CargasGroup.group.replaceView(guialayout);
```

onTabChanged wont work because the the activity that contains the list is not a TabActivity, and my problem is coming back from a subsequent activity, not a parallel one. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Check if onCreate is called? Did you tried starting another activity (I assume you are starting new activity) for result? Then in onActivityResult you can repopulate the listview...

Comment: Quick guess, during onResume() for your main activity, always call refresh on the list. Im guessing you have communication to your tabs figured out. Worst case, just reload the activity in the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got it working.
Created a static public instance of the activity inside itself (almost like a singleton).

```
public static MyActivity instance;
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    instance = this;
...
```

and a public method that reloads the data and refreshes the listview. Then the down-the-flux activity, accesses this instance and calls the method. 
Its dirty, but works.

Will accept my own answer as long as it gets upvoted (hoping for a cleaner solution).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to implement a Tab Activity in android.

Although you should receive onResume if you have different activities for handling different tabs, you can use onTabChanged() method to keep track of the tab user has selected and perform task accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, please check my question for updated info.

Answer (score 0):

In the activity that contains the listview override the onTabChanged() and call `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()` or `listView1.setAdapter(adapter)` to refresh the listview.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, please check my question for updated info.

Comment: Try overriding the onRestart() event of the activity. This is called after the user renavigates to the activity, which is what you are doing. If that doesn't work, you could also try overriding the onRestoreInstanceState() event. Click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestart()) for more info.

Comment: Tried logging with Log.d on both, no success.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change ure current activity to ActivityGroup

Comment: An ActivityGroup inside another?

Comment: Oh my God, im so sorry i was answering in a wrong window? i too had posted similar kind of question.